# Come tradurre "Sir"?

Tags: word-usage

Questa è una domanda un po'... personale, ma penso che possa essere utile.

Per rivolgersi in modo formale a una persona, in inglese si dice *Sir*, *Ma'am*, *Miss*.

In italiano, non ho problemi a usare "Signora" e "Signorina", ma "Signore" mi sembra sempre fuori luogo. 
Forse per l'uso religioso:

> Che il Signore sia con voi

forse perché mi sembra un po'... "infantile":

> Signore, mi sono perso

forse perché assume quasi un tono accusatorio/sarcastico:

> Mi scusi "signore", le sembra il caso di buttare la carta per terra?

Quindi uso soltanto "scusi".

È un mio blocco mentale, oppure altri la pensano allo stesso modo?

**Nel caso, esiste un modo migliore per tradurre *Sir*?**

Comment: Non la metto come risposta perché è più un commento soggettivo, ma “signore” mi sembra il modo di “default” per rivolgersi a un estraneo di sesso maschile. È sempre più raro, e comincia a suonare antiquato, perché si tende a dare del tu anche agli sconosciuti, o comunque a usare altri modi informali; ma in un conteso in cui a una donna ci si rivolge con “signora” mi sembra perfettamente naturale rivolgersi a un uomo con “signore”. Tutti gli altri sensi che menzioni (infantile, religioso, ironico) sono derivazioni di questo.

Comment: Riensandoci un po' su, mi pare veramente che ci sia una qualche difficoltà a rivolgersi a qualcuno direttamente con “signore”. Sto immaginando un cameriere di un ristorante elegante o un anziano barbiere, e forse è più facile che usino la terza persona («E il signore che cosa gradisce di secondo?») che non rivolgendosi direttamente all'interlocutore («Che cosa gradisce di secondo, signore?»). Domanda interessante, in effetti.

Comment: @DaG: a volte la terza persona formale potrebbe da sola bastare?

Comment: Perché il -1? Per favore chi lo mette si spieghi!

Comment: Credo che non si usi granché il termine signore per lo stesso motivo per cui, in italiano, spesso il soggetto è sottinteso. Se c'è funziona come una sorta di pronome. Inoltre mi sembra che l'uso di signorina sia ormai raro. Ho addirittura sentito parlare di una disposizione che imponesse, nei contesti ufficiali, di usare il solo termine signora per tutte le persone di sesso femminile maggiorenni.

Comment: Concordo con @DaG. Per rivolgersi direttamente a una persona che non si conosce, in genere basta il semplice «lei». Una domanda come «Il signore desidera?» ha un’aria di formalità eccessiva, finanche di cerimoniosità, in ogni contesto tranne, chessò?, in un ristorante stellato o un albergo cinque stelle.

Comment: @gabriele Interessante! Hai una fonte? 
Io al contrario userei "signorina" sempre, meglio sbagliarsi in difetto che in eccesso. Fa sicuramente piacere ;)

Comment: @writingthesis è una notizia che ho avuto da varie fonti, online e non, riportata da persone di una certa età. Il che mi fa pensare ad un fatto noto e discusso ai tempi della sua approvazione. Cercando online credo sia dovuto a questo manuale della Presidenza del Consiglio dei Ministri: [Il sessismo nella lingua italiana di Alma Sabatini](http://www.funzionepubblica.gov.it/media/962032/il%20sessismo%20nella%20lingua%20italiana.pdf), vedere a pag. 97 del PDF.

Comment: @gabriele: Sì, ma quelle della Sabatini sono raccomandazioni sull'uso della lingua, non certo “disposizioni”.

Answer (score 4):

***SIR*** usage:

> **Sir n   formal (mister) signore nm**
>       How can I help you, sir?
>       Come posso aiutarla, signore?
>
> **Sir n   (title) (titolo)    Sir nm**
>       Sir Walter Raleigh is famous.
>       Sir Walter Raleigh è famoso.
>
> **Sir [sb] vtr    (use sir with)  chiamare signore vtr**
>       Don't sir me! I'm not that old.
>       Non mi chiamare signore! Non sono così vecchio.
>
> **Dear Sir    formal (letter: formal greeting) (apertura di lettera)** egregio signore, pregiatissimo signore nm
>
> **No sir interj   formal (expressing polite negation) (forma di rispetto) no signore, nossignore**
>       No sir, I will not polish your shoes. No sir, you can put me in jail, but I refuse to fight.
>     No signore, non le luciderò le scarpe. Nossignore, mi può anche mettere in galera, ma mi rifiuto di combattere.
>
> **Yes sir**       sì, signore

Il vocabolario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/signore/) illustra molto bene l'uso di Signore nei modi odierni più comuni:

Signore:

> - Nell’uso odierno, **appellativo rispettoso, premesso al cognome**: il signor Rossi; o al nome: il signor Mario; o al nome e cognome: il signor Mario Rossi; nell’indirizzo di lettere o di altre missive (di solito nell’abbreviazione grafica sig.): al sig. Mario Rossi.
>
>   **Premesso a un titolo professionale o nobiliare, è di uso volutamente deferente e ormai disusato:** il signor avvocato la riceverà tra pochi minuti; il signor presidente, il signor ministro, formule ufficiali dopo l’abolizione del titolo di eccellenza; e **ugualmente antiquato è l’uso con un nome che esprime rapporto di parentela** mi saluti il suo signor padre (o anche il signore suo padre); in questi casi, e quando è seguito dall’avverbio affermativo o negativo (signor sì, signor no), è usata sempre la forma tronca signor.
>
>   **Talvolta con tono iron.** i signori dirigenti farebbero bene a migliorare il servizio. **Con uso assol., come appellativo rispettoso:** Signori della Corte; Signore e Signori, iniziando una conferenza o altro discorso; Ill.mo Signore, a principio di una lettera; anche rivolgendo la parola a un estraneo: signore, può dirmi l’ora? In risposte affermative o negative: sì signore, no signore; signor sì, signor no, formule preferite in alcuni ambienti come meno secche, più cortesi del semplice sì e no (anche in una sola parola: sissignore, nossignore, signorsì, signornò).
>
>   **Talvolta con funzione di soggetto, o di complemento, come equivalente di un pronome di terza persona sing. o plur., con tono di maggiore rispetto:** il s. desidera?, domanda che il negoziante rivolge al cliente; il s. è servito; se i signori vogliono accomodarsi; come desiderano lor signori; in questi ultimi casi il plur. signori può intendersi riferito all’insieme di signori e signore.

Al di fuori di questi casi, in senso più generale rivolgendosi ad un estraneo, userei la terza persona singolare come forma di rispetto senza l'uso dell'appellativo  *signore* o *signora*.

- mi scusi, mi può dire che ore sono?
- mi scusi, le sembra il caso di buttare la carta per terra?
- le spiace darmi una mano per favore?