# Difference between 'bello' and 'amico'?

Tags: word-usage

I apologize if the question is confusing- I am completely new to the Italian language and need this for a story I am writing.

I have two male characters who have just met, and one is attempting to flirt with the other on first greeting. In that circumstance, would the man most likely say something along the lines of, "Hey, *amico*," or "Hey, *bello*"? I am attempting to create a kind of "Hey, cutie," kind of vibe, for lack of better words.

Again, if my word usage is completely wrong, please correct me!

Thank you!

Comment: Of the two I'd say *Hey, bello* (lit. *hello, beautiful*). *Hey, amico* means *Hey, friend* and has no flirty connotation. I think there might be some better option, maybe *Hey, carino* (this is possibly a bit too flirty)

Comment: The LGBT community might have its own slang, BTW, nowadays "amico" is used ironically in Italy and for a reason: if one is an actual friend, you use his birth name; if he is not you use Sir, Mr., "Excuse me" and the likes. So you use "Hey amico" when what follows is intended to be unpleasant.

Comment: @antonio: In Italian is quite rare to use “Sir”, “Mr.”, “Excuse me” and so on, but we sometimes use *signore*, *scusi* and so on.

Comment: *Amico* to address someone is something that nowadays is done only in films or by foreigners.

Comment: *Ciao bello* and *ciao caro*, are two common expressions that friends or also collegues use on  a confidential basis. There is no romantic or sexual connotation. Context is everything as usual.

Comment: In which part of Italy you have heard this sentence?

Comment: To go on a tangent: in Italian there is no such word as “hey”. The analogous exclamation is *ehi*.

Comment: @DaG: Sir/Madam, Mr/Ms, are simply the Italian equivalent for Signore/a. Signore, desidera un drink? -> Would you like a drink, Sir?  
Signor Rossi, desidera un drink? -> Would you like a drink, Mr. Rossi? 
In Italy, it is very impolite to address someone (and particularly a woman), using just the Sur/name without using these polite forms or the professional title, unless he or she is a friend or is quite young.

Comment: @antonio, sei italiano? “Sir/Madam, Mr/Ms” non sono l'equivalente italiano di “Signore/a”, semmai il contrario, ma con tante e tali sfumature e distinzioni che non è possibile dare una corrispondenza uno a uno. Quindi, se vuoi spiegare quali appellativi si usano in italiano, dilli in italiano, sennò sembra che in italiano diciamo “Sir” alla gente, e tieni anche presente quello che è stato detto [qui](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5414/come-tradurre-sir).

Comment: @antonio La mia impressione (vivendo in un paese anglofono) è che "Sir/Madam" siano l'equivalente di "dare del lei" in inglese. Per esempio *Excuse me, sir/madam?* è l'equivalente di *Mi scusi?*. Ci sono poi sfumature di significato che dipendono dall'aggiungere o meno il cognome dopo l'epiteto e da dove si mettono le virgole, ma sono troppo esoteriche per me.

Answer (score 1):

In Italian, you don't have a direct translation for these kinds of stuff that wouldn't sound awkward...

Let's try to sort things out:

```
1. Ciao bello
2. Ciao carino 
3. Ciao bellezza
4. Ciao amico
5. Ciao tesoro
```

The first expression may be used to flirt

```
Ciao bello/a cosa fai stasera?
```

The 2nd expression, *carino* would be translated as **cutie** and it's usually used if you have confidence with the other person

The 3rd one is (basically) always used with **females** (when you approach them and still want to create a "sexy" atmosphere)

```
Ciao amico
```

Means literally `Hi friend`

The 5th one is used when you have a higher confidence with the person you are talking to...

Very used by couples.

Comment: We're talking about a man being flirtatious with another man. Any of your examples except _Ciao amico_ could be appropriate as a (trivial and a bit cheesy) pick-up line. I guess _Ciao tesoro_ is acceptable too, in a kind of ironic way, even if they don't know each other. I wouldn't mind about _bellezza_ being usually reserved to women, words of affection perceived as "gendered" among straight people are used in a very different way in a gay context as far as I know.